# Infer type from subclass method return type

Tags: python, oop, typing

I'm trying to infer a type from the returned type of a subclass method.
So far I haven't been able to make this work without making Parent a generic class (which I'd like to avoid).

The Parent class will be in a lib to be imported and create subclasses of.

Any idea how to do that ?
Thanks a lot.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, Iterable, Optional, TypeVar, Type

TRetType = TypeVar("TRetType")
TChild = TypeVar("TChild", bound="Parent")


class Parent:
    def run(self) -> Any:
        return "foo"

    @classmethod
    def run_children(cls: Type[TChild], children: Iterable[TChild]) -> Iterable[TRetType]:
        for child in children:
            ret: TRetType = child.run() # <--- attempt to force TRetType to the return type of child.run(), in that case, int
            yield ret


class Child(Parent):
    def run(self) -> int: # <--- the type that children_res should be of
        return 1


c = [Child() for _ in range(3)]
children_res = Child.run_children(c) # <--- children_res has no type
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible; there's no way to infer the return type of `run` from just the `TChild` type var.

I assume that you don't want to make `Parent` generic because there's no higher-kinded types in Python? I imagine what you'd ideally do is something like:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
R = TypeVar("R")
TChild = HigherKindedTypeVar("TChild", bound="Parent")


class Parent(Generic[T]):
    def run(self) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def run_children(cls: Type[TChild[R]], children: Iterable[TChild[R]]) -> Iterable[R]:
        ...


class Child(Parent[int]):
    def run(self) -> int: # <--- the type that children_res should be of
        return 1
```

*(Note that the above is pseudocode)*

---

Without higher-kinded types, you'd have to either enforce the `TChild` constraint (so that `children`'s elements are the same type as the class), or the return type constraint (so `childrens`'s elements can be any `Parent` subclass, as long as they return the given type). You can choose which to enforce depending on your use case.

Here's an example of the latter ([mypy-play link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=664b90af44eaeb6fa1c89c07c07d2196)):

```
T = TypeVar("T")
R = TypeVar("R")

class Parent(Generic[T]):
    def run(self) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def run_children(cls: Type[Parent[R]], children: Iterable[Parent[R]]) -> Iterable[R]:
        # Use `R` because `T` is already bound in class scope.
        ...

class IntChild1(Parent[int]):
    def run(self) -> int:
        return 1

class IntChild2(Parent[int]):
    def run(self) -> int:
        return 2

class StrChild(Parent[str]):
    def run(self) -> str:
        return "str"

IntChild1.run_children([IntChild1()])
IntChild1.run_children([IntChild2()])
IntChild1.run_children([StrChild()])  # error

IntChild2.run_children([IntChild1()])
IntChild2.run_children([IntChild2()])
IntChild2.run_children([StrChild()])  # error

StrChild.run_children([IntChild1()])  # error
StrChild.run_children([IntChild2()])  # error
StrChild.run_children([StrChild()])
```